# Should I get a smaller chainring or bigger cog?

Tags: parts, chainring, fixed-gear, single-speed, sprocket

I built a single speed bike about a year ago, and am starting to change out parts to make it more comfortable for me. The first thing I'm wanting to change is the gear inches, which I didn't give much thought to at the time of riding. I have a 700x25c [wheel](https://www.citygrounds.com/collections/bike-wheels-rims-hubs/products/x-speed-fixie-flip-flop-track-wheelset?variant=23875792262) with a 16t cog , and a 46T [chainring](https://www.citygrounds.com/collections/bike-cranksets-chainrings/products/sugino-pista-crankset?variant=32314911180) that also has a 165mm crank arm. If I calculated the gear inches right, it's 79.2 in. I'm in a pretty hilly area, and I'm wanting to see what effect having a gear inch more around 70 in will have. I'm thinking of either getting a chainring that is 40 teeth or getting a cog that is 18 teeth. Is there any argument for which would be better to replace? Also, is there anything else I should be thinking about or considering when purchasing them?

Comment: Is it correct that you would be replacing 16T cog with a 16T cog?

Comment: Oops, that was a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: It's generally easier/cheaper to replace the cog.  Though of course you will need a longer chain.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Looks like this is a single-speed or a fixie.  The rear wheel should then be mounted in slots designed to allow for swapping of the rear cog with one of a different size without having to change the chain at all (within reason).

Comment: Having a larger rear cog means a larger radius there. This could be positive for chain wear and efficiency if you buy into the idea... Ceramic Speed sell expensive rear derailleur cogs with extra teeth on that promise but it could be somewhat marginal!

Comment: @Swifty why would that mean less chain wear and more efficiency to have a larger cog?

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark the idea is that the chain is bent around a less tight curve, so each pivot of the chain then rotates through a lesser angle, causing less friction in the chain in every link. That's the idea, but I don't think it's enough to be a compelling answer to your question, so only worth a comment. I'm not even taking a view on it, just voicing the thought

Comment: Correct - smaller gears mean more drivetrain loss, and fewer teeth to spread wear over.  On the plus side, smaller gears weigh less which reduces overall bike weight.

Comment: Another thought is the number of skid patches.  Depending on the ratio between chainring and cog, you may end up with more or fewer braking skid spots.  The lower the number, the faster your tyre will wear through in those areas.  40/16 gives you two skid patches which is terrible.   41/16 would give you 16 skid patches which is great, means your rear tyre will last 8 times longer.    Or a 17 tooth cog works well with 35-50 tooth chainrings.  https://www.bikecalc.com/skid_patch_calculator

Comment: Don't skid. Give hipsters a brake.

Comment: I don't skid unless I really need to

Answer (score 1):

For the same gear ratio, more teeth each end means:

- More weight
- Weaker chainring
- More chain
- Reduced angle at each chain pin as it wraps round the sprocket.
- Potentially reduced vibration (this is complicated, I'll work on an edit later)

Comment: Also more teeth to spread force over, so they will wear out slower?